# Run cocos2d-x project in browser

Tags: javascript, c++, html, cross-platform, cocos2d-x

I have done some research and can't find a direct easy way to run my cocos2d-x project which is built in c++ on the web. If anyone has a solution besides re-writing my code in js or html I would love to hear it. Things I have tried so far...

- **Emscripten** : I was able to convert cpp/c files in js and run them using this, but I would like an easy way to run a whole project, rather than individual class files. Cocos2d has iffy support using Emscripten and there isn't great documentation to get this to work. If anyone has success with this, please guide me.

  - http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/Emscripten_usage: This is quite outdated the new cocos2d-x doesn't seem to support emscripten. I tried using an older version and wasn't able to get this guide to work.
- **Marmalade** : It looks like this can be done with cocos2d-x but you have to alter the code to work with marmalade to port to the web. I am not interested in doing this especially if I have to purchase marmalade without knowing for sure the quality and results. Does anyone have positive results using Marmalade's Quick/OpenQuick?

  - http://www.cocos2d-x.org/news/88
  - https://github.com/marmalade/OpenQuick
  - Info from the Marmalade forums: https://answers.madewithmarmalade.com/questions/35860/port-cocos2d-x-project-to-web.html
- **NaCl** : It seems promising but it isn't updated very well. Anyone have success with this?

  - http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/Native_Client_Environment_Setup
  - Using this tutorial I can't get the page to load correctly :
    https://developer.chrome.com/native-client/devguide/tutorial/tutorial-part1
  - https://github.com/sbc100/cocos2d-x/tree/nacl_port

Looking forward to hearing other alternatives and thoughts. I posted the same question in cocos2d forumns: http://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/t/run-cocos2d-x-project-in-browser/25224

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe doing it in cocos2d-js is actually the right solution.